# Why can you use the square of an area when differentiating to determine the maximum and minimum value

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, maxima-minima

my lecturer recently showed us that when finding a maximum or minimum value of a rectangle, if the equation is too tedious to differentiate normally, we can instead take the square of the equation instead to differentiate.

The Equation was this,

> Let r be a constant,
> $$
> A=4x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}
> $$
> He then said this would be too time consuming to differentiate normally in an exam and squared the whole function before differentiating.
> $$
> A^2=16x^2(r^2-x^2)
> $$
> $$
> W=A^2
> $$
> $$
> f'(W)=32r^2-64x^3
> $$

He did not explain why you could do this but I am curious about why in this case it is alright to do this?

Comment: Pick a simple function $f(x)$ and compare its critical points to those of $\sqrt{f(x)}$

Comment: I suppose the last formula should be $$W'(x)=32r^2x-64x^3.$$

Comment: You want to find the points at which $A'=0.$ If you know the points at which $(A^2)'=2AA'\equiv0,$ then if $A≠0$ at those points, they also maximize $A.$ In our example, $A>0$ because a rectangle has to have both of its sidelengths greater than zero to be a rectangle and not a line.

Answer (score 3):

This works because for $A$ greater than or equal to $0$, $A^2$ is a monotonically increasing function of $A$. If you find parameters that maximize/minimize $A^2$, they will also maximize/minimize $A$.

You could in theory apply any monotonic transformation like multiplication, a logarithm, or exponentiation, the square just happens to make the derivative more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

First reason if the square of a function has an extremum, the functin itself has also. Formal reason:: if you differentiate,the squaroot  goes to the nominator, The derivative of the Square is in the denominator which has to be zero.